# PHP - Multiple MySQL Connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok so this is my code for the **connection:**

```
$servername = "host";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$db1 = "db1";
$db2 = "db2";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db1); // $db1 is here as the default, is this ok?
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Then I run a function with this connection and it works for the `$db1`:

```
$sql = "SELECT etc etc;                 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

etc etc

The problem is when I try to change the db to `$db2`, I use this:

```
$conn->select_db($db2);
```

And now it only returns the value of the 2nd Database `($db2)`, and the one from `$db1` doesn't show up on the page anymore, it doesn't show any value.

Thanks for Reading.

Comment: Question seems to be incorrect : PHP - Multiple `MySQL` Connections. It should be PHP - Multiple MySQLi Connections

Comment: @NareshKumar.P MySQL is the database, mysqli is the API.

Comment: You need to show more code. The results of the first query shouldn't be affected by selecting a different database after you do the query and display the results.

Comment: Note also that it isn't necessary to select each database. If you want to access a table in a database other than the default, just add the database prefix to the query: `SELECT ... FROM db2.tablename`

Comment: i know that, its not another table its another database, i'm going to post more code soon

Comment: I ended up coding like Naresh Kumar.P said, thanks all for the help tho

Comment: @Pwned. If you find my code is useful you can up vote my answer by accepting my answer since it will be useful for others while facing the same problem right . Glad to help you and awaiting for your reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use two different connections while connecting different databases:

Database One Connection:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db1);
$sql = "SELECT etc etc;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Database Two Connection:

```
$conn1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db2);
$sql = "SELECT etc etc;
$result = $conn1->query($sql);
```

The Problem is that you have already assigned the `conn` to DB1 and hence if you run by selecting the DB2 it will be displaying error or no results will be produced. Hence while selecting multi databases you can use different connection variables.

Comment: You don't have to use different connections. The whole point of `select_db()` is to be able to switch default databases on the fly within a connection.

Comment: @Barmer .. Is it possible to get connection to another db have another username/pass ?

Comment: @safinchacko. By using the method as i have suggested you can get the connection on the go If you have multiple databases with different username and passwords.

Answer (score 0):

> the one from $db1 doesn't show up on the page anymore, it doesn't show any value.

what about making it `$conn->select_db($db1);` back?

Comment: The page is like this: db1 value, db2 value, when db2 value appears db1 value is gonne

Comment: @Pwned What happens when two DB has diff username/pass ?

Answer (score 0):

Create two config files

**db1.php**

```
$servername = "host1";
$username = "user1";
$password = "pass1";
$db = "db1";
```

**db2.php**

```
$servername = "host2";
$username = "user2";
$password = "pass2";
$db = "db2";


//connection to db1
include("db1.php");
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db); 
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//db1 codes

--------------------
//connection to db2
include("db2.php");
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db); 
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//db2 codes
```